# Why is my coffee script not detecting that an element isn't present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, coffeescript, query-string, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have hte following coffee script ...

```
  query_data_val = $.query.get('order_by')
  alert(query_data_val)
  if !query_data_val?
    ...
  else
    alert("branch 2")
```

I notice that even when I have no "order_by=" in my URL's query string, the above evaluates to brnach 2, even though I would expect it to evaluate to the first clause of the "if" statement.  Nothing gets printed out in the first alert dialog.  So waht is the right way, in coffee script, to check if a parameter is missing or empty? (Note that I would also want "order_by=&otehr_param=abc" to evaluate to the first branch since no value was provided for "order_by").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're thinking that the `?` works like `present?` in Rails. But it returns true unless the variable is null or undefined. I would imagine the `get` is returning an empty string, which will be truthy.

Try:

```
if query_data_val?.length
  alert 'present' + query_data_val
else
  alert 'not present'
```

Comment: I think you meant "!query_data_val?.length" to make the clause function like I intende, but i get your point.